Thunderbird upgrade to snap (24.04.1) - won't open with original profile - how to correct?
Have just upgraded from Jammy to Ubuntu 24.04.1 and Thunderbird can't seem to find my old profile.  It looks as if the original profile has been copied into the snap/Thunderbird directory, but when I run Thunderbird it asks me to set up my accounts from scratch.  Other questions on this issue do not provide sufficient info for me to work out how to fix it. Can someone help, please?

did you use the export tool in the original version before upgrading?

Graham, no I didn't - should I have?

it would have made life sooo much easier. For example, I changed from TB to Betterbird (a Flatpak fork of TB) and it was a cinch to  migrate between packages. And I've done the same between OS versions too. If your email accounts are IMAP, you won't lose anything by making the zip file at any stage, storing it somewhere safe and then importing later when required.

Thanks, but it's too late for that.  I had hoped it might be fixed by simply moving profile info from the old version to the new, but it is clearly more complicated than that and that didn't work.  Am still open to suggestions.

Ok, so I've now sorted it out.  Thanks for all the help - well, actually only graham, who at least gave me a clue as to where to look!
I had tried simply copying my original profile contents to the new profile (for the snap version of Thunderbird), but this didn't work at all. Nor did using "import profile" in the "tools" section of Thunderbird.  What did finally work was that I created a new profile in the snap version and then  copied the contents of my original (non-snap) profile into the new profile, telling it to "merge" the contents of all directories.
Once that had completed, I restarted Thunderbird and it restored all my messages, etc.
Posted in case it is of use to anyone else.

my migration from TB (apt -> snap) did not succeeded during upgrade from Ubuntu 22.04 to 24.04 : because network was offline and download was not not possible... as already known :-(
After (successful) upgrade, installation in "App Center" of TB did run well: but import of apt profile failed because my user partition was out of space, the App itself did NOT displayed this major problem for me !!!

I had tried simply copying my original profile contents to the new profile (for the snap version of Thunderbird)

Solution above failed also : I moved my emails like described, but merge op and editing of profile.ini was not enough. Error with calendar...
After running "snap install thunderbird" from console, I got the "out-space" error. After freeing space, I re-installed snap TB package. First run of TB do import automatically the apt profile and emails without problem.
=> try also this version 128.5.1 :-)
user@lenovo:~$ snap remove --purge thunderbird
thunderbird removed
user@lenovo:~$ snap install thunderbird
thunderbird 128.5.1esr-1 from Canonical✓ installed
user@lenovo:~$ thunderbird
Importing existing thunderbird profiles from /home/user/.thunderbird
Found default profile: h5spasas.default
Import done in 338.178 s (9 GB)

